# position:absolute dom locate unexpectedly when scroll

Tags: html, css

here is a demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }       
    .wrapper {
      height: 300px;
      width: 500px;
      overflow: scroll;
      position: relative;
    }       
    p {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }      
    span.tag {
      position: absolute;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: deepskyblue;
      color: white;
    }       
    .tl {
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }       
    .tr {
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
      </p>
    </div>
    <span class="tag tl">TopLeft</span>
    <span class="tag tr">TopRight</span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Basically I **expected** the four `span.tag` to stay the corner of the
div.wrapper viewport(it is so called I guess),because I've set `div.wrapper` position relative and `span.tag` position absolute , but when I scroll it, why it doesn't stay at the corner of viewport? is there anything about the `overflow:scroll`?

I thought `div.wrapper` has a height of 300px, so if the content of it has a larger height, a scroll-bar appear, we can scroll it, but what we scroll is the content, the wrapper doesn't move, so why the tag which set `top:0` didn't stay at the top the wrapper?

[EDIT]

this is the result I want:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .wrapper {
      height: 300px;
      width: 500px;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    .newlyAdded {
      height: 100%;
      overflow: scroll;
    }
    
    p {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    span.tag {
      position: absolute;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: deepskyblue;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .tl {
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    
    .tr {
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="newlyAdded">
      <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      </div>
      <span class="tag tl">TopLeft</span>
      <span class="tag tr">TopRight</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

But I still don't know why.

Comment: no, `fixed` is used for locate dom based on the whole page ,I just wanna the `span.tag` to stay the same place of the `div.wrapper`'s viewport.

Comment: can you explain to me more, so you want the fixed behavior but inside the element(not the whole page)?

Comment: yeah, that's what I want and it would be better if you could explain.

Comment: if you add `position: relative` to the parent div (like I see in your code) so the `fixed` use  the parent with `relative`... so just change to `fixed` most of the work is done by default (with your code)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `position: fixed` instead of `absolute`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

> a `fixed` element doesn't move also if you have a scrollbar
>
>  the behavior of `fixed` normally use the viewport, 
> but if you use a `position: relative;` on the parent element,
>
> you can get the behavior inside that element and not the page.

[image]

> as you see is not the whole page, but inside the parent element

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .wrapper {
      height: 300px;
      width: 500px;
      overflow: scroll;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    p {
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    
    span.tag {
      position: fixed;
      padding: 10px;
      background-color: deepskyblue;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .tl {
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    
    .tr {
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
      </p>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
      </p>
    </div>
    <span class="tag tl">TopLeft</span>
    <span class="tag tr">TopRight</span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I see now, I don't know why in my vscode code, works fine (image in the answer) and here on StackOverflow snippet don't work.